# How do you echo more than one thing with line break tags?

Tags: php, echo

I am currently using the below code to echo a few different variables and 2 line breaks.

But what I would like to know is how can I echo all of the variables including line breaks into one line of code?

```
<?php

function findworld($var) {
    return strpos($var, "world");
}

$firstvar = "hello world";
$secondvar = findworld($firstvar);
$thirdvar = strlen($firstvar);

echo $firstvar;
echo "<br />";
echo $secondvar;
echo "<br />";
echo $thirdvar;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the concat operator in php is "."

```
echo $firstvar . "<br />" .  $secondvar .  "<br />" . $thirdvar;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 4):

You can pass multiple parameters to [**`echo`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), separated by a comma:

```
echo $firstvar, "<br />", $secondvar, "<br />", $thirdvar;
```

To avoid repeating the line break, you could also use [**`implode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$firstvar = "hello world";
$values = array($firstvar, 
                findworld($firstvar), 
                strlen($firstvar));

echo implode('<br />', $values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation:

```
echo $firstvar . "<br />" . $secondvar . "<br />" . $thirdvar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, but with speech marks in the all the correct places ;)

```
echo $firstvar.'<br />'.$secondvar.'<br />'.$thirdvar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate at all with double quotes, you can just:

```
echo "$firstvar<br />$secondvar<br />$thirdvar";
```